# What is Wolfram Alpha returning when I ask it to calculate $\mathcal{L}[e^{x^2}](s)$?

Tags: laplace-transform

As my instructor mentioned more times than could ever seem necessary, arguments of the Laplace transform have to have growth of exponential or less.

[I typed this "nonexample" into W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace+transform+e%5E%28x%5E2%29) and noticed that it returned a reasonable answer in terms of Dawson functions and an imaginary term.

Assuming this is not an error, what version of the Laplace transform produces this result? Does the inverse Laplace transform produce the original function? I am curious as to what formula they use to calculate this because I cannot find any literature relating to an extension of the Laplace transform.

[This integral definition of the laplace transform](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%28-st%29e%5E%28x%5E2%29+from+0+to+infinity) does not converge.

Comment: Note that the correct input is $$\displaystyle{e^{-sx}e^{x^2}}$$, replacing the $t$ with an $x$. But it doesn't converge, either...

Comment: What is the "extension" you are seeking? If you mean generalization then there a many generalizations of the Laplace transform. The Laplace transform used by Wolfram is the only Laplace transform, namely, \begin{align} \mathcal{L}\{f; t\rightarrow s\} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t) \ dt \doteqdot f(s) \end{align}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the Laplace transform of $e^{x^{2}}$. 
\begin{align}
e^{t^{2}} &\doteqdot \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st + t^{2}} dt \\
&\doteqdot \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(t-s/2)^{2}- s^{2}/4} \ dt \\
&\doteqdot e^{- s^{2}/4} \ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(t-s/2)^{2}} \ dt \\
&\doteqdot e^{- s^{2}/4} \ \int_{-s/2}^{\infty} e^{u^{2}} du = e^{-s^{2}/4} 
\left[ \int_{-s/2}^{0} + \int_{0}^{\infty} \right] e^{u^{2}} du \\
&\doteqdot e^{- s^{2}/4} \ \int_{0}^{s/2} e^{u^{2}} du + i e^{-s^{2}/4} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^{2}} dt \\
&\doteqdot F\left( \frac{s}{2} \right) + \frac{i \sqrt{\pi}}{2} \ e^{- s^{2}/4} 
\end{align}
where $F(z)$ is Dawson's Integral given by
\begin{align}
F(z) = e^{- z^{2}} \int_{0}^{z} e^{u^{2}} du.
\end{align}

Comment: This is a nicely written argument, but I think you might have missed the point of the question.

Comment: What does the equals sign with the two dots mean?

Comment: @Potato It is an equivalence notation for transforms. Used more so in the older days. ie \begin{align} f(s) \doteqdot \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t) dt \end{align}.

Comment: So, for what values of $s$ does the integral (as originally written) converge, then?  It is not clear to me that it should converge for any.

Comment: How did you go from $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} e^{u^2} du$ to $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t^2} dt$? Shouldnt you be using a substitution $u=i*w$ and get $\displaystyle\int_0^{i \infty} e^{-w^2} dw$ which of course diverges?